# jQuery each not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I am trying to set a custom width and height for each item in the selector and it won't work. I'm at a loss. Everything looks correct to me. Am I missing a syntax error or something? The console.log doesn't even work.

```
<div id="posts">
    <article>
        <div class="view">
            ...
        </div>
    </article>

    <article>
        <div class="view">
            ...
        </div>
    </article>
    ...
</div>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#posts .view" ).each(function(){
        console.log('Testing');
        $(this).css("height", "400px");  
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Do you get any error message in the console?

Comment: looks fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/53R3T/1/

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/qz8Lm/

Comment: @ArunPJohny jsfiddle load jquery automatically...may be OP missing that part.

Comment: I'd imagine this is working, but you have some other CSS rules which are preventing it from displaying correctly.

Comment: Are you trying console.log in IE?  This has some known issues.  Failing that, I can't see any errors and the above fiddle looks alright to me.  I suggest trying a few different browsers and perhaps different debugging software (firebug can be handy).

EDIT: As mentioned above, if you're having CSS clashes - this can cause issues.  Or, if you're not including the jQuery library, it wont work at all.

Comment: the jQuery isnt in a script tag

Comment: On a side not you could do that in pure CSS as well: `#posts .view{height: 400px;}`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<div id="posts">
<article>
    <div class="view">
        ...
    </div>
</article>

<article>
    <div class="view">
        ...
    </div>
</article>
...
```

```
<script>

$( document ).ready(function() {
$( "#posts .view" ).each(function(){
    console.log('Testing');
    $(this).css("height", "400px");  
});
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<div id="posts">
    <article>
        <div class="view">
            ...
        </div>
    </article>

    <article>
        <div class="view">
            ...
        </div>
    </article>
    ...
</div>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#posts .view" ).each(function(){
        console.log('Testing');
        $(this).css("height", "400px");  
    });
});
</script>
```

Added script tags in case what you posted in your question was the full markup

Answer (score 0):

A bit optimized version:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#posts" ).find( ".view" ).each(function(){
        console.log('Testing');
        $(this).css("height", 400);  
    });
});
```